# Can't set simple attribute for image

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I want all photos to be bottom-aligned (to be closer to it's title). I also want titles to stay in one row. I've tried to add margin-bottom, vertical-align for IMG, A, and DIV, but nothing happens. What I doing wrong ? Please, help me.

http://domdekora.net/photos

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, on your styles.css you need to change two things to get this working.

on line 339 for style: content2 .gallerypage table.grid td you need to set vertical-align to bottom (instead of top).

Then on line 343 for style: content2 .gallerypage table.grid div/image_g you need to remove the height: 200px

That fixes it.

Comment: you're welcome :) I just played with the styles using firebug.

Comment: Yes, I was playing too, but can't get needed :/

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set your `.image_g` class to display as a table-cell and then align everything to the bottom, like so:

```
.image_g {
display:table-cell;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```